# Button click event not firing mobile in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using reactjs for a login form and on the click event the client makes a request to the server with the details... For some reason when I click on mobile nothing happens.. I tried adding the cursor: pointer; property to the css file but nothing happens still. Any help is appreciated.

Code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./login.styles.css";
import { setAccessToken, getAccessToken } from "../../authorization";

export class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      accessToken: getAccessToken(),
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(getAccessToken());
  }

  changeHandle = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  submitHandle = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://linkhere.example/api/users/login",
        this.state
      );
      setAccessToken(response.data.accessToken);
      console.log(response.data.accessToken);
      this.setState({ accessToken: response.data.accessToken });
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <body className="color">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="image">
            <img alt="login" src={require("./Login.png")}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="top-text">
            {this.state.accessToken ? <h1>{this.state.accessToken}</h1> : null}
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
            <h3>Sign in to your account...</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="login-info">
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={(e) => this.changeHandle(e)}
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <br></br>
            <input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={(e) => this.changeHandle(e)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <button onClick={this.submitHandle} type="submit">
              Log In
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

button css

```
.login-info button {
    color: #FFDEDE;
    background-color: #3a1c4d;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in that CSS that looks like button { cursor: pointer } ?

Comment: Give your button a z-index value of something like `z-index: 999` and see what happens. You might just have another div/component covering your button. Also, put an `alert('test')` inside your `submitHandle` function before and after the try and see if the alert happens. This will tell you if your function is actually executing or not.

Comment: @MattMorgan Adding `{ cursor: pointer } ` to the css wouldn't cause any change to whether the button was working or not, it would just change the cursor to a pointing hand. This is `react-native` though, so would it have any effect at all? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sam if you search SO, you'll find there are some instances with this as a known issue with React in mobile browsers.  And the post doesn't _say_ this is react-native.  Also the imports indicate that it is not.

Comment: @MattMorgan Sorry, I thought I read `react-native` in the tags

Comment: I put the wrong thing for the button css i accidentally put my input... the z-index did not work for some reason.... I am going to try putting an alert before the try block

Comment: @Sam it seems to be an issue with axios... I am not sure why but it is returning network error

Comment: @infecting Try a different link and see if that changes anything